# JAX-WS Spring premature end of file. Line 1 XML

Tags: spring, namespaces, jax-ws

im using Jax-WS with Spring and my ApplicationContext not show any errors, but when i start my tomcat generates an XML error.

my applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<wss:binding url="/hello">
    <wss:service>
        <ws:service bean="#helloWs"/>
    </wss:service>
</wss:binding>

<!-- Web service methods -->
<bean id="helloWs" class="br.com.myproject.ws.HelloWorldWS">
    <property name="helloWorldBo" ref="HelloWorldBo" />
</bean>

<bean id="HelloWorldBo" class="br.com.myproject.ws.HelloWorldBoImpl" />
</beans>
```

this error generated:

`GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)`

Comment: are you sure your applicationContext.xml is actually packaged in your war file and is present under /WEB-INF ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, From you schema definition for location, you are missing with `dev.` for some part like core and servlet xsd for jaxws definition.

it should be as below:

```
http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
   http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
   http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
   http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd
```

The above problem will be resolved.